# replacing a wrong date with the correct date in R

Tags: r

I can't seem to find a solution on here, please let me know if there is already one thanks!

I have a column in r with date and time, some of which are wrong. I am hoping to change the incorrect ones to the correct ones.

The data is in POSIXct. I have duplicated the original column so I can modify the new one.
An example of what the data looks like,

```
id <- c(1:5)
opdate <- c(2018-03-01 11:50:00 UTC, 2018-03-02 09:35:00 UTC, 2018-02-27 17:00:00 UTC, 2018-03-06 09:00:00 UTC, 2018-03-08 08:40:00 UTC)
```

I want to change the date for opdate[3] to "2018-03-08 10:05:00 UTC"

I have tried

```
opdate[3] <- "2018-03-08 10:05:00 UTC"
```

and

```
opdate [3] <- "2018-03-08 10:05:00 UTC", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

but it's not working, I think it is probably something basic but I don't know what

ideally, the output for the ammended opdate would be

```
2018-03-01 11:50:00 UTC, 2018-03-02 09:35:00 UTC, 2018-03-08 10:05:00 UTC, 2018-03-06 09:00:00 UTC, 2018-03-08 08:40:00 UTC
```

but it comes up with error that there is an unexpected numeric constant

Comment: Try `as.POSIXct("2018-03-08 10:05:00", tz = "UTC")`

Comment: If that doesn't work, please [edit] your question and provide working, syntactically-correct code. It can be difficult to distinguish between proper code that is mis-behaving, and code that will never be parsed (and the coder may not understand the difference).

Comment: this worked, thank you very much! really appreciate it :)